# Define a function in a matlab's shell session

Tags: matlab, shell, emacs, org-mode

I know that in matlab, functions are supposed to live in their own file. But what about matlab shell? Is there a way to define function in the shell?

I am asking because I am using matlab in org-mode in emacs, and all my code has to be executed my a session, as a result I cannot define functions, which very annoying to say the least.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Anonymous Functions in MATLAB:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html

Comment: The problem with that is that they can contain only a single executable statement

Comment: You can still write fairly complex routines using them: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/24/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-2/

Comment: Implementing loops: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/07/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-3/

Comment: It is not possible to define any other functions, if anonymous functions are not sufficient for your case, it is not possible.

Comment: It technically is possible to define more than a single statement with anonymous functions if you use `eval` but this is very dangerous and highly non-recommended.  I used it as a way of saving bytes when I was code golfing for this challenge here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58891/dont-google-google/58911#58911

Comment: Even if you use `eval` to pack more than one statement, you won't be able to define intermediate variables. For example, the following gives an error: `f = @(x) eval('y = x.^2; log(y)'); f(3)`